# FFmpeg efficient capture from rtsp ipcamera

Tags: ffmpeg, synchronization, rtsp, cut, capture

I need to capture an audio/video rtsp stream uncompressed in a file from ipcamera. Audio (pcm_alaw) and video (h264) must be synchronized. It is necessary that the file does not get corrupted if the camera loses the connection for a few moments (mp4).

At the moment I use the command below, but the ts codec does not support pcm_alaw and therefore the audio is not heard:

```
ffmpeg -stimeout 2000000 -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://admin:1234@192.168.5.22/h264 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts -y main.ts
```

I use the mpegts codec because I need to check the duration of the capture in real time with the command:

```
ffprobe -i /home/pi/NAS/main.mov -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

If i use mkv or avi its output would be:

```
N/A
```

The verification of the duration is important because I capture files of about 3 hours and at my choice I perform some data while the capture is in progress. I prefer not to compress the audio because I have often noticed some asynchrony with respect to the video when cutting.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `-c:a copy` you can use `-c:a aac` or `-c:a mp3` to convert the audio stream before you save it.

MPEG-TS h264 is only compatible with mp3 or aac ([source](https://www.epiphan.com/userguides/pearl-2/Content/UserGuides/Streaming/capture/channelCodecFormatCompat.htm)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As mentioned, however, I would like to avoid video and audio compression. It has happened several times that compressing the ffmpeg audio stops without ending the process thus finding small files.

Comment: You can only have mp3 or aac for mpeg-ts. So the only solutions are changing the camera output codec or convert it

Comment: Also with the hls method you always have small files (except if you want everything in a single file). And why would the audio stop when you re-encode and not when you copy?

Comment: I have no idea, sometimes I find the ts file very small despite the date of change matches the end of the recording.

Comment: La the solution would be to capture in an mkv file but I can't read the duration while it's capturing the stream. Is there a way?